# hide the fact that an email is sent from gmail's web interface

Tags: email, web, smtp, gmail

Does anyone know if you can hide or modify some of the header fields from the sent email via the Gmail web interface?

such as:

```
X-Gmail-Original-Message-ID: xxxxxxxxxxxx@mail.gmail.com
Message-ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxx@mail.gmail.com
```

My idea would be to completely fake (hide the fact) that the said email was sent from the Gmail web interface. The goal of that would be simple - use Gmail even if the company you work for, does not allow it.

Perhaps there is a Gmail extension for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can only change the **from email** when sending email from Gmail. Take a look at [Send emails from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en).

Also, there are techniques to really find out where an email came from; forging email headers and/or spoofing emails is something that spammers do and will get your IP address blacklisted by your ISP.

You can also check [How can I find out where an email really came from?](https://superuser.com/questions/624509/how-can-i-find-out-where-an-email-really-came-from). The headers can also be put in [SpamCop](https://www.spamcop.net/) and let them do the trace work with an option of sending a SPAM notice to the responsible sysadmin.